# Autocorrelation of Geometric Process

Tags: statistics, correlation, expected-value

I have this scenario where $S[n] = 0$ if an email does not arrive and $S[n] = 1$ if an email arrives in the $n^{th}$ minute. Therefore, $S[n]$ follows a Bernoulli distribution.  Now $U[m]$ is the number of minutes between the $m^{th}$ and $(m+1)^{th}$ email where $m = 0, 1, 2, 3...$. Therefore, $U[m]$ follows a Geometric distribution. Also $P(S[n] = 0) = p$, therefore, I have concluded that,

$P_{U[m]}(m) = p^{m}(1-p)$

I am required to determine the autocorrelation of $U[m]$, and so far, I have:

$R_{UU}[m, m+p] = E[U[m]] \times E[U[m+p]] = \frac{p^2}{(1-p)^2}$ for $p \ne 0$

But for $p = 0$, I need to find:

$E[U^2[m]] = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}u_m^2 \cdot P_{U[m]}(m)$

Which is also:

$E[U^2[m]] = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}m^2 \cdot (1-p) \cdot p^m$

$E[U^2[m]] = (1-p) \cdot p \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}m^2 \cdot p^{m-1}$

Now I am not sure how to proceed?

Comment: You should have that $\mathbb P(U[m]=k) = p^{k-1}(1-p)$ for $k\geqslant1$. It is still a geometric distribution, but there must be at least one minute between each mail, so the index starts at one.

Comment: More importantly, there shouldn't be any autocorrelation in this process. The random variables in the sequence $U[m]$ are the increments of a Bernoulli process, which are independent.

Comment: The question states that $m=0, 1, 2, 3, …$, that is why I used P
$P_{U[m]}(m) = p^m (1-p)$.  The question also has an answer, (given below), I am just trying to figure out how to reach that answer. The answer is $R_{UU}(m, m + p) = \frac{p^2}{(1-p)^2} + \frac{p}{(1-p)^2}\delta[-p].$